# system call to curl doesnt shows output from a ruby script

Tags: ruby, curl

I have a ruby script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

`curl -X GET http://host/someurl'
```

The response doesnt get displayed on terminal when I run this script:

```
$ ./script.rb 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   146    0   146    0     0     73      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--    73
$
```

The server does send some data. If I supply -o  to curl:

```
`curl -X GET -o <some_file> http://host/someurl'
```

some_file contains server response. Same works for POST requests though:

```
`curl -X POST --data-binary @some_file http://host/someurl'
```

This shows the response on terminal. Any idea how I fix this?

Comment: I guess I am missing something here. Where is the ruby script? Just using a ruby shebang and adding .rb at the end doesnt make it a ruby script imo.

Answer (score 3):

just puts it

```
puts `curl -X GET http://host/someurl`
```

Comment: @constantine1 pay attention to this answer. Make sure you understand what backticks do: they capture the standard output from the command and **return** it as a string. You must do something with that return value, either pass it to method (like `puts`) or assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo closing your back-tick shell command.  You want:

```
`curl -X GET http://host/someurl`
```

You used a single quotation mark instead of a trailing back-tick.  This causes the expression not to be terminated.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was just an error in pasting it here; I am enclosing it in ``